# Setting a reference to a cell and then modifying its contents

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I am typing:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) + 1
```

I'd vastly prefer to set a reference to the cell and use that about it rather than typing out `ActiveCell.Offset` every time. I tried to set it as a range called `sick`:

```
Dim sick As Range
Set sick = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
```

but it didn't work when I said `sick = sick + 1`. It said that was a type mismatch. Why?

Comment: There was probably text in the cell you were trying to add 1 to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is because sick is of type range. You can access its value using the value property like this:

```
sick.value = sick.value + 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid but it works now. I just didn't know I had to say sick.value. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Hm... `.Value` is the default property of the `Range` type, so this should be exactly equivalent to `sick = sick + 1`. That can't be the reason it worked; @user2994436 must have inadvertently changed something else that made it work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I know this, but I have also noted that in some situations VBA, for some reason, will not evaluate to the `Value` property if not explicitly called.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that your `sick` cell contained data of a non-numeric type, probably a string (i.e. text).

I tried your code; `sick = sick + 1` worked just fine for me -- as long as the `sick` cell contained numeric data (or data that VBA could interpret as such). However I was able to reproduce your Type mismatch error if `sick` contained a string.

Note that `.Value` is the default property of the Range type, so

```
sick = sick + 1
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
sick.Value = sick.Value + 1
```

These two lines can be used interchangeably. Some prefer the latter because it's more explicit what you're doing. Others the former because it's more concise. It's purely a matter of taste.